# Show toast every time opens android app

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I want to show a welcome toast every time I open the application. The above code is working but it shows also the welcome toast every time the screen rotating.

```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WELCOME!!!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Is there a way to show the toast only one time in every opening of the app?

manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.im.gernan" >   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<application
    android:name="com.example.im.gernan.MyAppCtx"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Store a boolean called `welcomeShown` and change it in `onCreate`?

Comment: just add to your manifest this line android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: put one boolean flag in shared preferences http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thank you all.Is working now with ApplicationContext class.I add the manifest to show the reference of the context class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, add a flag to indicate if it was shown or not.
One place could be the Activity himself, but the activity can be finished and reopend in the time the app is active. The lifecycle of the application context only knows onCreate and onDestroy and keeps the hole app session, which is to prefere to make your toast realy only coming up once the app has started.

Example:

This could be an application context class, referenced in manifest as application.

```
public MyAppCtx extends Application {
  public boolean toasted = false;
}
```

Then in any activity you can do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    if (!((MyAppCtx)getApplicationContext()).toasted) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WELCOME!!!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((MyAppCtx)getApplicationContext()).toasted = true;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now when this activity starts it checks the application context if you had shown your welcome or not. If not it shows and sets the switch. Thats all. Have fun

Comment: so I have to add a new class named MyAppCtx and add the first code there?can I do this without adding new class?

Comment: You could, but when you had read. It depends on the lifecycle of the different parts. If you put that flag in an activity, it will be reset when the activity reenters the whole lifecycle, which can happen in one app usage. But I never written an app, which doesn't end up having my own app context. Because it makes your life so much easer. There is an answer using the preferences, that works too and keeps the information over several app starts.

Comment: Thats it.Working great.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can have a boolean in your ApplicationContext or a singleton somewhere to store if your toast was shown already - if yes do not show the toast again

Answer (score 0):

declare one variable

```
static boolean value=false;
if(value==false)
{
value=true;
//show welcome toast
}
```